# Is there a way to use Laravel Eloquent for a Poly-polumorphic relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm trying to model the following scenario:

I have multiple models and they can mention each other multiple times.

So, for instance, a POST can mention other posts, comments, organizations, and so on. Comments can also mention whatever they want and so on.

My best  poke at the actual DB design is this, and it's fine IMO if I'm using raw SQL. I don't want to lose eloquent perks, though, so would anyone have a tip on how to do it using Laravel's ORM?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, what is wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: I don't see why this would hinder you from using the eloquent syntax. Could you maybe give an example where your struggles are?

Comment: I tried eloquent morphMany() method, but it expects a model as a related Model. Can't think of a way of making it flexible multiple ways

Comment: Why not use `morphTo()` ... then you can `morphMany()` directly to that function

Answer (score 1):

Your polymorphic database model

```
class Mentioned extends Model
{
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Any model that can be a "mentioner", add this `mentioners` function (ie, `\App\Models\Post`)

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function mentioners()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Mentioned::class, 'model');
    }
}
```

Now simply just use

```
Post::with('mentioners')->first();
```

Or, for ease, write it as a trait:

```
trait Mentioner
{
    public function mentioners()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Mentioned::class, 'model');
    }
}
```

Now, inside your models just use it:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use Mentioner;
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    use Mentioner;
}

# elsewhere
Post::with('mentioners')->first();
Comment::with('mentioners')->first();
```

Comment: So, that's the way I was doing, but all the results come with the Mentioned class, not the class it's supposed to

Comment: ... This works perfectly fine for me, not sure what you're doing but it deffo aint that.